# How to serialize json string value to class in Newtonsoft Json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

If I have the following model class

```
public class User
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string UUID {get; set;}
}
```

The following JSON string would be converted correctly

```
// JSON 1
{
  "User": {
    "Name": "Hello World",
    "UUID": "000000-00000-00000"
  }
}
```

In my case sometimes I have the following JSON `JSON 2` that the `User` JSON property represents `UUID` value instead of a User Model Object

```
// JSON 2
{
  "User": "000000-00000-00000"
}
```

I want to use the `User` class as **ASP.Net Core** action parameter model, which means I might need a custom `JsonConverter`.

Is there any way to convert the JSON string above to `User` Class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class UserJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(User);

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, 
        object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var token = JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var user = new User();
        // Convert string
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.String)
        {
            user.UUID = token.Value<string>();
        }
        // Convert object
        else
        {
            serializer.Populate(token.CreateReader(), user);
        }

        return user;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
    }
}
```

This works for:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(UserJsonConverter))]
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UUID { get; set; }
}

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(
@"{
  ""User"": {
    ""Name"": ""Hello World"",
    ""UUID"": ""000000-00000-00000""
  }
}");

var obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(
@"{
  ""User"": ""000000-00000-00000""
}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Customize a JsonConverter like below:

```
public class UserJsonConverter:JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(User);

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
        object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var token = JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var user = new User();

        // Convert object
        if (token.SelectToken("User").HasValues)
        {
            user.Name = token.SelectToken("User.Name").ToString();
            user.UUID = token.SelectToken("User.UUID").ToString();
        }
        // Convert string
        else
        {
            user.UUID = token.SelectToken("User").ToString();
        }

        return user;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
    }
}
```

Result
[image]